# PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in testreg.php on line 32

Tags: php, javascript, база-данных, apache, mysqli

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, boolean given in testreg.php on line 53

2 ошибки но как их исправить ??

```
<?php session_start();// вся процедура работает на сессиях. Именно в
    ней хранятся данные пользователя, пока он находится на сайте. Очень
    важно запустить их в самом начале странички!!!

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) { $login = $_POST['login']; if ($login
    == '') { unset($login);} } //заносим введенный пользователем логин в переменную $login, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную if
    (isset($_POST['password'])) { $password=$_POST['password']; if
    ($password =='') { unset($password);} } //заносим введенный
    пользователем пароль в переменную $password, если он пустой, то
    уничтожаем переменную

    if (empty($login) or empty($password)) //если пользователь не ввел
    логин или пароль, то выдаем ошибку и останавливаем скрипт { exit
    ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, венитесь назад и заполните все
    поля!"); } //если логин и пароль введены,то обрабатываем их, чтобы
    теги и скрипты не работали, мало ли что люди могут ввести $login =
    stripslashes($login); $login = htmlspecialchars($login);

    $password = stripslashes($password); $password =
    htmlspecialchars($password);

    //удаляем лишние пробелы
              $login = trim($login);
              $password = trim($password);

    // заменяем новым********************************************
                // подключаемся к базе
                include ("bd.php");// файл bd.php должен быть в той    же папке, что и все остальные, если это не так, то просто измените
    путь           // минипроверка на подбор паролей

                $ip=getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
                if (empty($ip) || $ip=='unknown') {    $ip=getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"); }//извлекаем ip            mysqli_query
    ($db,"DELETE FROM oshibka WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() -   
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) > 900");//удаляем ip-адреса ошибавшихся при
    входе пользователей через 15 минут.            $result =
    mysqli_query($db,"SELECT col FROM oshibka WHERE    ip='$ip'");//
    извлекаем из базы количество неудачных попыток входа за    последние
    15 у пользователя с данным ip 
                $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if ($myrow['col'] > 2) {
                //если ошибок больше двух, т.е три, то выдаем сообщение.
                exit("Вы набрали логин или пароль неверно 3 раз. Подождите    15 минут до следующей попытки.");
                }           $password    = md5($password);//шифруем пароль
                $password    = strrev($password);// для надежности добавим реверс
                $password    = $password."b3p6f";

                //можно добавить несколько своих символов по вкусу, например,    вписав "b3p6f". Если этот пароль будут взламывать
    методом подбора у    себя на сервере этой же md5,то явно ничего
    хорошего не    выйдет. Но советую ставить другие символы, можно в
    начале строки или в    середине.           //При этом необходимо
    увеличить длину поля password в базе. Зашифрованный пароль может
    получится гораздо большего    размера.            

    $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM    users WHERE
    login='$login' AND    password='$password'"); //извлекаем из базы
    все данные о пользователе с    введенным логином и паролем
                $myrow    = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                if (empty($myrow['id']))
                {
                //если пользователя с введенным логином и паролем не    существует
                //Делаем запись о том, что данный ip не смог войти.           $select = mysqli_query ($db,"SELECT ip FROM oshibka WHERE   
    ip='$ip'");
             $tmp = mysqli_fetch_row($select);
                if ($ip == $tmp[0]) {//проверяем, есть ли пользователь в таблице "oshibka" 
                $result52 = mysqli_query("SELECT col FROM oshibka WHERE    ip='$ip'",$db);
                $myrow52 = mysqli_fetch_array($result52);           $col = $myrow52[0] + 1;//прибавляем    еще одну попытку неудачного входа 
                mysqli_query ("UPDATE oshibka SET col=$col,date=NOW() WHERE    ip='$ip'");
                }           else {
                mysqli_query ($db,"INSERT INTO oshibka (ip,date,col) VALUES    ('$ip',NOW(),'1')");
                //если за последние 15 минут ошибок не было, то вставляем    новую запись в таблицу "oshibka"
                }          
                exit ("Извините, введённый    вами логин или пароль неверный.");
                }
                else {           nbsp;         //если пароли    совпадают, то запускаем пользователю сессию! Можете его поздравить,
    он вошел!
                          $_SESSION['password']=$myrow['password']; 
                                    $_SESSION['login']=$myrow['login']; 

                          $_SESSION['id']=$myrow['id'];//эти    данные очень часто используются, вот их и будет "носить с собой"   
    вошедший пользователь

                //Далее мы запоминаем данные в куки, для последующего входа.
                //ВНИМАНИЕ!!! ДЕЛАЙТЕ ЭТО НА ВАШЕ УСМОТРЕНИЕ, ТАК КАК ДАННЫЕ ХРАНЯТСЯ    В КУКАХ БЕЗ ШИФРОВКИ

                if ($_POST['save'] == 1) {
                //Если пользователь хочет, чтобы его данные сохранились для    последующего входа, то сохраняем в куках его браузера
                setcookie("login",    $_POST["login"], time()+9999999);
                setcookie("password",    $_POST["password"], time()+9999999);
                }}                  
                echo "<html><head><meta    http-equiv='Refresh' content='0;    URL=index.php'></head></html>";//перенаправляем
    пользователя на главную страничку, там    ему и сообщим об удачном
    входе           ?>
```

Comment: Но ответа так какового я от них не узнал или не получил и еще + это mysqli больше всего

Comment: При чём тут [tag:mysql] или [tag:mysqli]. У вас же всё в ошибке (предупреждение) чётко сказано, что не очень то хорошо использовать булевый тип там, где его быть не может